# Error displaying/logging isn't working with default logging.php

Tags: php, laravel

I have the default config/logging.php but the synatx errors, and any other errors aren't displayed/logged. The browser continues the load until CPU usages becomes high.

```
Route::get('/', function () {

    \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log::info( print_r( 'Here', true ) );

    sdf << syntax error not shown.
} );
```

However, when manually logged it's logged: 'Here'.

Comment: So to clarify, in the above code the `'Here'` is logged but the syntax error is not?